# OneDrive shared appFolder

Tags: c#, uwp, onedrive

I'm using the c# UWP [OneDrive Api](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/) and have two questions:

1. Is the exchange (sending and receiving) of files + login via this API always encrypted?
2. Is it possible to share the Special Folder [App Root](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/special_folders.htm) with two Apps? Like I have an App A, which is free and an App A pro, which costs something and I want to make it very easy for the user to use his/her data from App A in App A pro without him/her having to change anything, but just login to OneDrive and the App fetches the necessary data from App A free version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All connections to the OneDrive API are via https encrypted channels.

The `App` aspect is build around the application id that you use to communicate with the OneDrive service, you could have two separate applications on a Android/iOS app stores one free and one paid that use the same underlying application id.